# Why I am not getting second element in array?

Tags: bash

I am trying to create indexed array for variable free_memlist but it's only  printing first one. But inside loop it is fine.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
eval array_host=($(xe host-list params=uuid | cut -c 17-))
#Loop through each xen server node

for i in ${array_host[@]};

do

free_mem1=$(xe host-data-source-query data-source=memory_free_kib uuid=$i)

free_mem=( ${free_mem1/\.*} )


done

host_memlist=($free_mem)
echo ${array_host[0]}
echo ${array_host[1]}
echo ${free_mem[0]}
echo ${free_mem[1]}
```

Output:

```
63c2fe78-48c2-4c48-b7dd-f68f8639a7af
6264dd23-76c9-4905-894f-a5fb212aa8dc
2921184
```

Expected Output:

```
63c2fe78-48c2-4c48-b7dd-f68f8639a7af
6264dd23-76c9-4905-894f-a5fb212aa8dc
2921184
2721184
```

Output of command:xe host-list params=uuid | cut -c 17- as below:

```
63c2fe78-48c2-4c48-b7dd-f68f8639a7af


6264dd23-76c9-4905-894f-a5fb212aa8dc
```

Don't know what's wrong with the code.

Comment: Add output of `xe host-list params=uuid | cut -c 17-` to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus, Please check the output of the command. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use `eval`? `array_host` will be filled without calling it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Yes, but I couldn't see any difference in output using it and without using it. Thanks.

Comment: `eval` can be deadly dangerous if you do not know exactly what you are providing to it. (heaven forbid the bytes making up the array resolve to `sudo rm -rf /`) So do not use it unless it is absolutely necessary and you know exactly what you are providing to it `:)`

Comment: Unless I'm wrong, the line `free_mem=( ${free_mem1/\.*} )` is overwriting $free_mem, not making a new array entry. Does replacing that line with `free_mem+=( ${free_mem1/\.*} )` fix the problem?

Comment: @Guest2, Thank you so much. That fixed the problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Resubmitting as an answer, as requested;

The line `free_mem=( ${free_mem1/\.*} )` is overwriting `$free_mem`, not making a new array entry. Appending to an array is done with `+=`. and replacing that line with `free_mem+=( ${free_mem1/\.*} )` appends as expected.